# Best way to bring the contents of a textfile into a reflex project

Tags: haskell, reflex

I have a 70 line text file, whose contents I want to have as the initial value of a text area within my project.  What is the best way to do this? Normally I would use `readFile` but I can't seem to use it in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Template Haskell to load the file at compile time and store its contents in a toplevel definition. [The `file-embed` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed) on Hackage implements this functionality for you:

> This module uses Template Haskell. Following is a simplified
>   explanation of usage for those unfamiliar with calling Template
>   Haskell functions.
>
> The function `embedFile` in this modules embeds a file into the
>   executable that you can use it at runtime. A file is represented as a
>   `ByteString`. However, as you can see below, the type signature
>   indicates a value of type `Q Exp` will be returned. In order to
>   convert this into a `ByteString`, you must use Template Haskell
>   syntax, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $(embedFile "myfile.txt")
> ```
>
> This expression will have type `ByteString`.